# Data URI not found in img src tag

Tags: javascript, image, uri, webcam

So I'm using this library

https://github.com/jhuckaby/webcamjs

I get a data uri for the web cam image and I pass it into a template like this

```
    this.$el.append(this.template.render({
        imageUri: imageUri
    }));
```

Where the template looks like -

```
<img src=<%= imageUri.imageUri %>/>
```

When I console log the imageUri, it is clickable in the console and when I click on it, I see the image in the browser.

However, I get an error with the template like this -

```
GET (imageUri) net::ERR_INVALID_URL
```

Why is it suddenly invalid in the img src, but not when I click on it in console?

Answer (score 0):

What are the `<%`, is that webforms syntax? If so, you need quotes:

```
<img src='<%= imageUri.imageUri %>'/>
```

The source needs to be in quotes when it is rendered.